# RoboCopy issues moving files and directories, with exceptions

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

```
ROBOCOPY %current_path% %current_path%previous_version * /e /MOV   /XF update.bat previous_version _new_update
```

It moves files and folders but leaves behind empty folder e.g. contents of folder `x` are moved to previous_version but leaves behind an empty folder, and also moves `_new_update` folder which I don't want to move.

Comment: If `_new_update` is a directory you don't want to move, why have you listed it as an excluded file, `/XF`, and not an excluded directory, `/XD`? I'm assuming that you should also include `previous_version` under the `/XD` option too! Please open a Command Prompt window, type `robocopy /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information.

Comment: @Compo after move is done it leaves behind empty directories

Comment: Did you read my previous comment, and follow its advice? or just read it? I ask because my first instinct when reading the usage information is to check what the options used actually do. Had you done that you'd have noted that the `/XF` option you had used was only for files, and just as importantly that the `/MOV` option you've used is also only for files. Try the `/MOVE` option instead! It takes only a few minutes to read the usage information, and not the six and a half hours it has taken since you joined up, and for me to spoon feed you the same information.

Comment: [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)`/MOV` moves files, `/MOVE` moves files and directories…